# Meteor inserting objects from one collection to another bug

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

By click I add record from one collection to another. But a lot of times it adds an empty object. Here I tried to add some timeout and check if there is an `_id` attribute, and the amount of empty objects has reduced, but there are still some empty objects, when click too often. Is this a known bug? Is there any way to get around this?

```
timeout = false;

Template.clients.events({

    'click': function() {

        if(typeof this._id !== 'undefined' && !timeout) {

            timeout = true;

            TempCol.insert(this, function() {

                var tmt = 300 + parseInt(Math.floor(Math.random() * (300 + 1)));

                setTimeout(function() { timeout = false; }, tmt);

            });
        }

    }

});
```

UPD: Actually, it gets the job done, but the question is still open: is that a bug or what?

Comment: Can you put together a repro on Github? 

I'd suggest console.log(this) at the start of the click handler so you can see what that object actually is when clicked.

Comment: Yes I did that. Sometimes there was an empty object - `Object {}`